# xcode displaying file list window when editing

Tags: xcode, window

When I cut or paste, and possibly other times, my xcode will suddenly pop open that upper window above my code display, the window that lists the file names and roles and code size. This only started happening today, so I'm wondering if I accidentally triggered some setting. It's really annoying as I drag the horizontal window bar up to cover it so I can maximize my code window view and it comes back down minutes later after some editing action (cut, paste, something). I don't know if this possibly has to do with my having a split window view (two code windows one above the other) perhaps.

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug related to split views. I do not have a solution, but I do have a workaround. Select the file you are editing and press enter. Then create a split view and open the next file the same way. You will now have a separate editor window with the two files. Since this window does not have the file lists, it cannot show them.

Comment: Your alternative is appreciated. I can't seem to get around the annoyance of needing to click on different files as I work and having to ultimately go back to the main window. I'll try to hone in on what action exactly is causing the issue.